# Get value inside of the same div

Tags: javascript

I read this topic (and some others):

[get value of sibling in same div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325660/get-value-of-sibling-in-same-div)

But still didn't gave me an awnser.

I have 2 divs with the same name (created by a loop). When `onClick` is fired i want to pass the value of the **idUser** to the `getNumber()` function and then show the **idUser** on the `p` tag

HTML:

```
<div id="telephoneButton">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" id="idUser">
    <input type="button" value="Show Number" onClick="
    getNumber(idUser.value);">              
    <p id="number"></p>
</div>

<div id="telephoneButton">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" id="idUser">
    <input type="button" value="Show Number" onClick="
    getNumber(idUser.value);">
    <p id="number"></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getNumber(idUser)
{
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = idUser;
}
```

I know this isn't going to work because everything has the same ids so the script will show an error (or maybe show the result on the first div). My question is, can i pass the father DIV of the button and get all the data i need on the script using children? If yes, how?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Usually, you don't duplicate the same id... you should use classes instead

Comment: You might want to consider using classes instead of IDs as classes are meant to be re-used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I have 2 divs with the same name"

> STOP RIGHT THERE!

**No two elements should ever have the same id.** You should adjust your loop that produces these elements so that they get produced with unique id values.

Now, you *can* make this work by gathering up both `div` elements and then digging inside them, like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

     // Assuming, of course that these are the only div elements on the page.
     // The selector here could be modified to be hierarchical, but you didn't
     // provide enough HTML to see that.
     var theDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
  
     // Loop through the div elements (no matter how many)
     for(var i = 0; i < theDivs.length; ++i){
       
         // Create an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) that passes itself
         // a COPY of the looping variable (i) so that each click callback will get its
         // own different value for it.
         (function(counter){
           
           // Wire up the button that is in the current div to a click event callback function
           theDivs[i].children[1].addEventListener("click", function() {
             
               // Call the getNumber function and pass it the data it needs and the right
               // paragraph to write that data into.
               getNumber(theDivs[counter].children[0].value, theDivs[counter].children[2]);
            });
           
         }(i));   
     }
  

    function getNumber(idUser, element){
       element.innerHTML = idUser;
    }
  
});
```

```html
<div id="telephoneButton">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" id="idUser">
    <input type="button" value="Show Number">              
    <p id="number"></p>
</div>

<div id="telephoneButton">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" id="idUser">
    <input type="button" value="Show Number">
    <p id="number"></p>
</div>

<div id="telephoneButton">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" id="idUser">
    <input type="button" value="Show Number">
    <p id="number"></p>
</div>

<div id="telephoneButton">
    <input type="hidden" value="4" id="idUser">
    <input type="button" value="Show Number">
    <p id="number"></p>
</div>

<div id="telephoneButton">
    <input type="hidden" value="5" id="idUser">
    <input type="button" value="Show Number">
    <p id="number"></p>
</div>
```

But, really, this is a hack. You should give all the important HTML elements unique `id` values or assign them to a CSS class so they can be identified uniquely later.

Also, don't use inline HTML event handlers (`... onclick=""`) as they create spaghetti code and create global function wrappers around the onXyz attribute value that modifies the `this` binding for the callback function. Additionally, they don't allow for more than one event handler per event. Instead, use the W3C DOM Event Model Standard of `element.addEventListener()`.

Comment: Thats a nice solution. But i forgot to add some important things, my loop does about 100 interactions. So i have about 100 telephoneButton divs. So this script would be huge and i would have to edit it every time someone add a new telephone number.

Comment: Well, not if the loop were creating unique id values, but the way you have it now, we have to manually hunt and peck for the right elements. Are you in control of the loop?  It wouldn't be hard to make sure each element gets a unique id. By the way, my code could be optimized to be a little less manual, but I wanted to show clearly what was happening.

Comment: Yes the loop is from a SQL select. Maybe i could do `id="telephone"+variable`? The question is how would this change the current code you wrote?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend that and I would do that will all the other elements as well (the buttons and the paragraphs), but I would give all the div elements the same CSS class (and all the buttons the same CSS class and all the paragraphs the same CSS class). This allows us to quickly get them into arrays and once in arrays, we can loop through them easily.

Comment: @Adrian I've updated my code snippet to show a more dynamic approach. It's a little advanced as it relies on JavaScript closures to get the job done properly.  There is another way to make it a bit simpler, but it relies on ECMAScript 6, which many browsers don't implement yet.

Comment: This will now accommodate as many repeating div sections as you may have. You can see that I've added a few more.

Comment: Thats a very beautiful solution. For one last question, since i have more than the telephoneButton div could i work with `<div class="telephoneButton">` and then call `var theDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".telephoneButton");`?

Comment: Yes. You just need a way to gather all the <div> elements up into a single container.

Comment: Thx a lot Scott, it worked like a charm. I'll get right away into addEventListener, sounds like a powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should solve your problem, but as the others jave been saying, you should be using things like names and classes to get hold of multiple variables inside the DOM. Here's the badboy solution, but you need to change both  to :

```
        var allElem = document.getElementsByTagName('telephoneButton');
        for (var i=0, max=allElem.length; i < max; i++) {
          alert(allElem[i].p.innerHTML);
        }
```

Comment: I went for the Scott solution. But thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 0):

As you know, have elements with same ids is really bad. But anyway this code work :

```
<div id="telephoneButton">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" id="idUser" />
    <input type="button" value="Show Number" onClick="getNumber(this);" />              
    <p id="number"></p>
</div>

<div id="telephoneButton">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" id="idUser" />
    <input type="button" value="Show Number" onClick=" getNumber(this);" />
    <p id="number"></p>
</div>
```

And JS :

```
var getNumber = function(elem) {
    var num = elem.parentElement.children[0].value;
    elem.parentElement.children[2].innerHTML = num;
}
```

See Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ugobsr79/2/

---

If you want to show all numbers at the same time then use this JS :

```
var getNumber = function(elem) {
    var idUsers = document.querySelectorAll('input[id="idUser"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < idUsers.length; i++) {
        var num = idUsers[i].value;
        idUsers[i].parentElement.children[2].innerHTML = num;
    }
}
```

Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/ugobsr79/3/

Comment: Thats a nice solution. I know its really bad but my loop have about 100 interactions, your solution (even if its a bad one) seems like the one that would work for a loop that is dynamic.

Comment: But i still have one problem. The onClick only work 1 time. If i want to show both idUser it wont work.

Comment: Thanks a lot wawawoom but what i really wanted to do was awnsered by Scott